# how to set button on bottom of window after click in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm working scroll related task.

I have a webpage, the webpage have breadcrumb and footer, breadcrumb is placed into top of footer and one click button, it poisitined on top of breadcrumb. whenever the end user scroll the page they can see the click button on top of breadcrumb. My current requirement is, whenever end user click the button, the button and breadcrumb should be on bottom of window, footer should be hiddend. Also if end user scroll after clicked the button, now they can scroll until bottom of the page.

I tried to implement this using scrollTo but its failed. Anyone please suggest how to implement this.

**JS:**

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var headerHeight = $('header').height(); // header part
    var bodyWrapperHeight = $('.body-wrapper').height(); // body part
    var windowBodyHeight = Math.abs(windowHeight) - Math.abs(bodyWrapperHeight);
    var scrollTotalWithHeader = Math.abs(windowBodyHeight) + Math.abs(headerHeight);
    var scrollTotalWithoutHeader = Math.abs(windowBodyHeight) - Math.abs(headerHeight);
    if(Math.abs(windowBodyHeight) > Math.abs(headerHeight)) {
        $("body, html").animate({
            scrollTop: Math.abs(scrollTotalWithHeader)
        }, {
            duration: 600,
            complete: function(){
                scrollLock = true;
            }
        });

    } else {
        $("body, html").animate({ 
            scrollTop: Math.abs(scrollTotalWithoutHeader)
        }, {
            duration: 600,
            complete: function(){
                scrollLock = true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. Do you have any of the following: code example; screenshots; working demo (jsfiddle, jsbin)?

Comment: @MattFletcher, sorry for delay. I have added my js codes

Answer (score 0):

sorry i really dont understand what u want

```js
var btn1=document.getElementById("btn1");
 var btn=document.getElementById("btn");

btn1.addEventListener("click", btnsettobtm);
function btnsettobtm()
{
 btn.style.position="fixed";
 btn.style.right="10px";
 btn.style.bottom="10px";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="btn1" id="btn1" value="button">


<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="Btn Is Here!">
```

if u can explain in simple or demo i can help u ,more easy ,sorry